# jest mocking toHaveReturnedWith undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm learning unit testing with jest and particularly mocking modules. I wrote some simple module in math.js file with some math methods:

```
const add      = (a, b) => a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) => b - a;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide   = (a, b) => b / a;

module.exports = {
    add,
    subtract,
    multiply,
    divide
}
```

Then I include it in my main js and I do module mocking like this:

```
jest.mock('./math.js');
const math = require('./math');

test("calls math.add", () => {
    math.add(1, 2);

    console.log(math.add.mock);

    expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
    expect(math.add).toHaveReturned();
    expect(math.add).toHaveReturnedWith(3);
});
```

Now when I run my test all tests are passing besides the last one:

```
expect(math.add).toHaveReturnedWith(3);
```

In console I see:

● calls math.add

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveReturnedWith(expected)

Expected: 3
Received: undefined

Number of returns: 1

  10 |     expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
  11 |     expect(math.add).toHaveReturned();
> 12 |     expect(math.add).toHaveReturnedWith(3);
     |                      ^
  13 | });
```

and console.log(math.add.mock) gives me this:

```
 console.log
      {
        calls: [ [ 1, 2 ] ],
        instances: [
          {
            add: [Function],
            subtract: [Function],
            multiply: [Function],
            divide: [Function]
          }
        ],
        invocationCallOrder: [ 1 ],
        results: [ { type: 'return', value: undefined } ],
        lastCall: [ 1, 2 ]
      }
```

So it seems that math.add mocked function does not return any value. My question is why? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `jest.mock('someModule')`, jest will create an auto-mocked version for this module. This means the exported things from this module are all mocked.

You can think that the mocked `math.add` method is `jest.fn()`. There is no mock implementation for it. If no implementation is given, the mock function will return `undefined` when invoked. That's why the `math.add(1, 2)` returns `undefined`.

You are testing the `math` module, then you should NOT mock it. But if you insist to do it. You can use `math.add.mockReturnValue(3);` before invoke the `math.add(1,2)`. But it doesn't make sense, you can give any value you want. You didn't test the real `math.add` method. You just match your mock return value to the assertion `expect(math.add).toHaveReturnedWith(3)`

E.g.
`math.js`:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) => b - a;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => b / a;

module.exports = {
  add,
  subtract,
  multiply,
  divide,
};
```

`math.test.js`:

```js
const math = require('./math');

jest.mock('./math.js');

test('calls math.add', () => {
  math.add.mockReturnValue(3);
  math.add(1, 2);

  expect(jest.isMockFunction(math.add)).toBeTruthy();

  expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 2);
  expect(math.add).toHaveReturned();
  expect(math.add).toHaveReturnedWith(3);
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71605818/math.test.js
  ✓ calls math.add (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |      20 |     100 |                   
 math.js  |     100 |      100 |      20 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.225 s
```

Comment: Why jest.mock's implementation is empty? As far as I understood mock functions they are used as spy functions, so we wrap the original function with mock function (or pass the mock function as callback) and then call the mock function instead of the original one. And in this way we get the information about the function we are interested in. What's the point of making a mock function with no implementation? Can you please clarify, I guess I probably don't understand correctly the point of making mock functions. How would look like the "meaningful" test in my case? Thank you in advance.